# How to make a variable be a condition?

Tags: javascript, variables, conditional-statements

I have been trying to make a variable have two values/be a condition. It's fine if this is not possible, but I would like to not have to type `68 || 39` every time I would like to check. I have tried `var left = 68 || 39` and `var left = 68 && 39`, but neither of those work. The variable is to check an `event.keyCode` number. I am trying to make my first game-in-javascript. Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Um, usually we'd use `if` for this purpose. And if you want this `if` to be a variable, I'd suggest looking into `variable = function() { return YourCondition; }`, which you can then call with `variable()`. Or you could store the result of your condition in the variable, which you then can check with `if` again.

Comment: Maybe it'd help if you told us, what exactly you're trying to do. What do you expect? And what happens? Because, as it were, both statements evaluate to `true`, because both operators are not 0.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Sorry if I didn't make sense, but I am using if but not in the variable, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium I expect it to act as if I typed `68 || 39`

Comment: Yes well, in that case, you can shorten that to `var left = true;`, because without anything to compare that value to, it will always evaluate to `true`. I believe what you want is a function you can call, as per the answer that's been posted by now.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Sorry if I didn't make sense, but I am comparing the left variable to a keypress number.

Comment: As I said: What you need is a function. `function pressedKey(keyCode) { return keyCode == 68 || keyCode == 39; }`, check it with `if (pressedKey(event.keyCode))` (or whatever) and you're done.

Comment: `const isKey = key => [39, 69].includes(key);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to make a variable be a condition but what you can do is define a method that checks if the value is 69 or 39.

For example:

```
function valueIs69or39(valueToCheck) {
    return valueToCheck == 69 || valueToCheck == 39;
}
```

now you can just use if (valueIs69or39(value)) to check, and you can shorten the method name to make it easier to type.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I suppose this works, I just feel that a variable would be cleaner.

Comment: Well @ArcadeSmasher, if you'd prefer a variable, you are free to store the result in a variable. `left = keyCode == 69 || keyCode == 39;` and later call it with `if (left)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple values that fulfil a condition what you really want to do is use a collection of values as your variable, instead of a single value.  i.e.  An array (or Set, or Map, there are many higher order collection types that are designed for different purposes)

Something like this:

```
let allowedValues = [ 69, 39 ];
```

You would then use a method to check those values:

```
function testValue( value ) {
    return allowedValues.includes(value)
}
```

Same thing with a Set (you might use a Set because it guarantees each element only appears once):

```
let allowedValues = new Set([ 39, 68 ])

function testValue(value) {
    return allowedValues.has(value)
}
```

Same thing but with a Set that is immutable (the allowed values cannot be changed dynamically):

```js
function testValue(value) {
    const allowedValues = new Set([ 39, 68 ])
    return allowedValues.has(value)
}

console.log(testValue(10))
console.log(testValue(39))
```